# Don't repopulate with redirect and flashdata doesn't work with $this->method CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I'm having problem with `redirect()` in **Codeigniter**.
My controller is:

```
   public function cadastraCliente(){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cliente', 'Cliente', 'trim|required|is_unique[cliente.id_pessoa]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('tipo_cliente', 'Tipo Cliente', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('obs', 'Observação', 'trim');

        $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'O campo <b>%s</b> é obrigatório!');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'Já existe um <b>%s</b> cadastrado!');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

            $flashdata = array('alert_type' => 'error','message' => '<b>Erro</b> ao cadastrar Cliente!');
            $this->session->set_flashdata($flashdata);
            $this->cliente();

        }else{

            $this->load->model('Cadastro_Model','cadastro');

            $cliente = $this->input->post();

            if($this->cadastro->setCliente($cliente))
                $flashdata = array('alert_type' => 'success','message' => '<b>Cliente</b> cadastrado com sucesso!');
            else
                $flashdata = array('alert_type' => 'error','message' => '<b>Erro</b> ao cadastrar cliente tente novamente!');

            $this->session->set_flashdata($flashdata);
            $this->cliente();
        }
```

If I use redirect('cliente') in place of `$this->cliente();` the set_value in form don't repopulate.
Otherwise if i use `$this->cliente();` the flashdata appear just when i change the page.

Someone knows why it happen?

Comment: what is the content of cliente function?

Comment: The content of client is just load->view

Answer (score 0):

I think you better use `$this->cliente();` when the form validation returns `false` because you are going to show the validation errors back in the form and of course you can't do this with `redirect()`.

And use `redirect()` when no validation errors came up. Then your `flashdata` will be shown in the next view. remember that in order for `flashdata` to be displayed, you need to use `redirect()`.

Comment: Help me but don't solve my problem because how can i use flashdata to show for example "Record 2 deleted"?